# DSUM Function Using Form Fields

Tags: ms-access, expression, ms-access-2013

I have a form which is used to submit entries to a Table.
The ‘Monthly Adjustment $’ Field currently posts new table entries which works fine.

[image]

I would like to display the total balance from the Raw Data Table in the ‘Current Balance $’ field filtered based on the Company and Accrual ID that is selected by the user in the Form.

Each time the user selects a new Company and Accrual ID combination in the Form I want the ‘Current Balance $’ field to display the total $ for that Company and Accrual combination from the Raw Data Table.

To start with I have tried using a DSUM in expression builder to sum the ‘Amount $’ field in the Raw Data table, where the Accrual ID is equal to whatever value the user has selected in the Form’s ‘Accrual ID’ field. The next step would be to then add a second filter for the company selected (which I will do once I figure this first bit out). I have included the expression I am using below.

=Nz(DSum("[Amount $]","Accruals Raw Data","[Accruals Raw Data]![Accrual ID]= ' " & [Forms]![Single Accrual Entry - Form]![Accrual ID] & " ' "))

However when I select an option in the Accrual ID field in the form it does not return any results in the Current Balance $ field. It just displays a blank box.

I can get the ‘Current Balance $’ to display the total $ amount from the table using DSUM (i.e. with no filters applied) but can’t get it to do the above.

Would appreciate your help.

Many Thanks

Comment: What is data type of `[Accrual ID]`? If Number, then remove single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove *spaces* if ID is text:

```
=Nz(DSum("[Amount $]","Accruals Raw Data","[Accrual ID]= '" & [Accrual ID] & "'"),0)
```

and remove *quotes* too if ID is numeric:

```
=Nz(DSum("[Amount $]","Accruals Raw Data","[Accrual ID]= " & [Accrual ID] & ""),0)
```

For two criteria try:

```
=Nz(DSum("[Amount $]","Accruals Raw Data","[Accrual ID]= '" & [Accrual ID] & "' And [Company] = '" & [Company] & "'"),0)
```

Comment: Hi Gustav. I tried the first option above (as accrual ID is text) and it doesn't seem to work, it returns a #Name? error in the field when I go into Form view.

Comment: Also when I enter in your formula above, it changes Me! to [Me]!. Not sure if that makes any difference? Thanks

Comment: Sorry. `Me` doesn't work in expressions used directly as ControlSource. You should be able to just specify the field/control. See edit.

Comment: Great, that worked! I need to include 2 criteria but it doesn't seem to return anything, any ideas? =nz(DSum("[Amount $]","Accruals Raw Data","[Accrual ID]= '" & [Accrual ID] & "'" & " AND [Company]= '" & [Company] & "'"),0)

Comment: It should work, though can be reduced slightly. See edit.